# Finding approximate value for $1003^{\frac{1}{3}}$ using derivative function.

Tags: calculus

**Question:**

Given that $y=x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ , find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and use it to find the approximate value of $1003^{\frac{1}{3}}$.

**My attempt:**

$y=x^{\frac{1}{3}}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=(\frac{1}{3}) (x^{\frac{-2}{3}})$

Let $x=1003$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=(\frac{1}{3}) (1003^{\frac{-2}{3}}) = 0.0033$

$\frac{\delta{y}}{\delta{x}} \approx \frac{dy}{dx}$

So, $\frac{\delta{y}}{\delta{x}} \approx 0.0033$

I’m stuck here.

Comment: Put $x= 1000, \delta x= 1003-1000=3$.

Comment: You're supposed to use the concept of "linear approximation". Look it up on google, you should be able to find some nice videos/ articles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Given that $y=x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ , find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and use it to find the approximate value of $1003^{\frac{1}{3}}$.

Note the problem wants you to use the first order approximation to estimate the value. In general,

$$f(x)\approx f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$$

So in your case, $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{3}}, x_0=1000,$ you want to estimate the value at $x=1003$, hence

$$\begin{align}f(1003)&\approx f(1000)+f'(1000)(1003-1000)\\
\\
1003^{\frac{1}{3}}&\approx1000^{\frac{1}{3}}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot1000^{-2/3}\cdot 3\end{align}$$

Can you proceed from here?